# Google Maps API and position of display

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I get the displayed map to be centered a little lower than the center of the location?

What I'm finding is that my info window is getting cut off at the top.

Here's the code:

```
if(jQuery("#map").length)
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'andrade motor car 975 Campbell Avenue West Haven, CT 06516' }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var loc = results[0].geometry.location;
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 17,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
            map.setCenter(loc);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map//,
                //icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("/assets/images/map_pointer.png", new google.maps.Size(38, 45), null, new google.maps.Point(18, 44))
            });         
            infobox = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                maxWidth: 400,
                  content: '<div style="width:300px !important;overflow:hidden !important;"><h2 class="shop-title">andrade motor car</h2><p>975 Campbell Avenue<br />West Haven, CT 06516<br />203-931-7575</div>'
              });
            infobox.open(map, marker);
            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat(), loc.lng()));
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });     
}
```

I initially thought that by doing something like:

```
map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat() - 1, loc.lng()));
```

may do the trick, but it made no difference

Comment: Did you try to change `pixelOffset` offset of infoWindow?

Comment: I did just now.  Wanna post that as an answer so I can award it.  It worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pixelOffset` option of infoWindow to move it as it suits you. For example:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    ...,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(20, 20)
});
```